# How to Pass Direceted Graph (adjacency list) into Dijkstra Algorithm Boost to find shortest path?

Tags: c++, algorithm, boost, graph-algorithm, boost-graph

I have written this Class as a start to build My Algorithm, but I can see Before word on console, but not After ! what is my mistake in using Dijkstra Algorithm of Boost ??

```
#include <myalgorithm.h>
#include<mygraphbuilder.h>
//===============================================
using namespace std;
using namespace boost;
//===============================================

MyAlgorithm::MyAlgorithm()// Default constructor
{
}
//===========================================================================
MyAlgorithm::MyAlgorithm(graph_t AnyGraph, Vertex VSource){//}, Vertex VTarget){ // Parameters Constructor

  MyGraph = AnyGraph;
  vector<Vertex> p(num_vertices(AnyGraph));
  vector<double> d(num_edges(AnyGraph));
  //===========================================================================
  //Dijkstra_Algorithm
  //===========================================================================
  cout<<"Before\t"<<endl;
  dijkstra_shortest_paths(AnyGraph, VSource,
                          predecessor_map(boost::make_iterator_property_map(p.begin(), get(boost::vertex_index, AnyGraph))).
                          distance_map(boost::make_iterator_property_map(d.begin(), get(boost::vertex_index, AnyGraph))));
 cout<<"After\t"<<endl;
  //===========================================================================
}// End of Parameters Constructor
//===========================================================================
MyAlgorithm::~MyAlgorithm(){ //Destructur
}
//===========================================================================
// Accessors
// function to call ShortPath
vector <Vertex> MyAlgorithm::getShortPath(){
  return MyAlgorithm::ShortPath;
}
// function to call the Graph
graph_t MyAlgorithm::getGraph(){
  return MyGraph;
}
//===========================================================================
// Mutators
//function to set short path Vector as whole
void MyAlgorithm::setShortPath(vector<Vertex> PathVector){
  MyAlgorithm::ResetShortPath();
  MyAlgorithm::ShortPath = PathVector;
}
//function to inject node to Short Path
void MyAlgorithm::setShortPath(Vertex MyNode){
  ShortPath.emplace_back(MyNode);
}
// function to set a graph
void MyAlgorithm::setGraph(graph_t YourGraph){
  MyGraph = YourGraph;
}
//============================================================================
//function to reset short path
void MyAlgorithm::ResetShortPath(){
  MyAlgorithm::ShortPath.clear();
}
//function to Print Out Results
void MyAlgorithm::PrintOut(){
  cout << "distances and parents:" << endl;
  graph_traits < graph_t >::vertex_iterator vi, vend;
  for (boost::tie(vi, vend) = vertices(MyAlgorithm::MyGraph); vi != vend; ++vi) {
      vector<Vertex> p(num_vertices(MyAlgorithm::MyGraph));
      vector<double> d(num_vertices(MyAlgorithm::MyGraph));
      cout << "distance(" << *vi << ") = " << d[*vi] << ", ";
      cout << "parent(" << *vi << ") = " << p[*vi] << endl;
    } // End of Print Loop
}// end of Print Function
```

My Graph is defined as following :

```
typedef adjacency_list < vecS, vecS, directedS, property < vertex_name_t, idType >, property < edge_weight_t, double > > graph_t;
```

Where idType is unsigned long long int; but it didn't work, how I can Make it work ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see what the question is. Your code would simply compile, see [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fead5a20355005f2).

That said

- you can probably do without copying the graph quite so many times
- you should make the distance-map to number of vertices instead of edges:

  ```
  std::vector<double> d(num_edges(MyGraph));
  ```

  is supposed to be

  ```
  std::vector<double> d(num_vertices(MyGraph));
  ```

## UPDATE

To the added code in the question:

- Like I said, you probably should not be copying quite so much. In particular, why does `MyAlgorithm` *own* a copy of `AnyGraph` as a member `MyGraph`? It is never used by your own constructor...
- Similarly, the added code has the same problem, specifically with

  ```
  for (auto v : make_iterator_range(vertices(MyGraph))) {
      std::vector<Vertex> p(num_vertices(MyGraph));
      std::vector<double> d(num_vertices(MyGraph));
      std::cout << "distance(" << v << ") = " << d[v] << ", ";
      std::cout << "parent(" << v << ") = " << p[v] << std::endl;
  }
  ```

  The `d` and `p` vectors are simply created with default-initialized values every iteration through the loop. What did you expect to find?
- I can **guess** that you intended the result of `dijkstra_shortest_paths` to be used there, but you never did anything to make that happen. At the very least it looks like you should have made `d` and `p` member varlables
- The `setShortPath` member functions are never used. By extension, the `ShortPath` member is never properly set. It seems you are aware of this because you also don't attempt to use it in `PrintOut`
- There is a conceptual problem with printing "The Shortest Path" as it obviously depends on the target vertex... I'd write a `getShortPath` accessor that calculates a specific path:

  ```
  Path getShortPath(Vertex destination) {
      Path path;

      while (destination != MyGraph.null_vertex()) {
          path.push_front(destination);
          if (destination == src)
              return path;

          if (predecessors.at(destination) == destination)
              break;
          destination = predecessors.at(destination);
      }
      throw std::runtime_error("Unreachable");
  }
  ```
- Now you can add a print function for any path:

  ```
  void PrintPath(MyAlgorithm::Path const& path, graph_t const& g) {
      std::cout << "Path: ";
      auto idmap = get(boost::vertex_name, g);
      auto wmap = get(boost::edge_weight, g);

      auto previous = g.null_vertex();
      for (auto v : path) {
          if (previous != g.null_vertex()) {
              for (auto e : make_iterator_range(out_edges(previous, g))) {
                  if (target(e, g) == v) {
                      std::cout << " -> (w:" << " << " << wmap[e] << ") ";
                  }
              }
          }
          std::cout << "#" << v << " (id:" << idmap[v] << ") ";
          previous = v;
      }
      std::cout << "\n";
  }
  ```

  It also prints weights on every edge (you will see it matches the total distance)

### Fixed Demo

Here's a version that fixes all of the above. I stopped generating random graphs as now the "test cases" make assumptions about which paths are reachable:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f298b135d49a850f)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/dag_shortest_paths.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graph_utility.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using boost::make_iterator_range;

using idType = unsigned long long;

typedef boost::adjacency_list<
    boost::vecS,
    boost::vecS,
    boost::directedS,
    boost::property<boost::vertex_name_t, idType>,
    boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, double>> graph_t;

struct MyGraphBuilder {
    void generate();
    void printGraph() const;

    graph_t const& getGraph() const { return MyGraph; }
    graph_t&       getGraph()       { return MyGraph; }
  private:
    graph_t MyGraph;
};

void MyGraphBuilder::printGraph() const {
    std::cout << "Number of Vertices is:" << num_vertices(MyGraph) << "\n";
    std::cout << "Number of Edges is:" << num_edges(MyGraph) << "\n";

    boost::print_graph(MyGraph, boost::get(boost::vertex_name, MyGraph), std::cout);

    // to print with edge weights:
    for (auto v : make_iterator_range(vertices(MyGraph))) {
        for (auto oe : make_iterator_range(out_edges(v, MyGraph))) {
            std::cout << "Edge " << oe << " weight " << get(boost::edge_weight, MyGraph, oe) << "\n";
        }
    }
}

void MyGraphBuilder::generate() {
    MyGraph = graph_t(5); // clear graph, 5 vertices

    auto idmap = get(boost::vertex_name, MyGraph);
    idmap[0] = 0ull;
    idmap[1] = 100ull;
    idmap[2] = 200ull;
    idmap[3] = 300ull;
    idmap[4] = 400ull;

    add_edge(1, 3, { 1.52275 }, MyGraph);
    add_edge(2, 0, { 8.79559 }, MyGraph);
    add_edge(2, 0, { 6.41004 }, MyGraph);
    add_edge(3, 2, { 7.37265 }, MyGraph);
    add_edge(4, 0, { 1.18526 }, MyGraph);
}

struct MyAlgorithm {
    using Vertex = graph_t::vertex_descriptor;

    graph_t MyGraph;
    Vertex src;
    std::vector<Vertex> predecessors;
    std::vector<double> distances;

    MyAlgorithm(graph_t const& AnyGraph, Vertex VSource)
        : MyGraph(AnyGraph),
          src(VSource),
          predecessors(num_vertices(MyGraph)),
          distances(num_vertices(MyGraph))
    {
        dijkstra_shortest_paths(MyGraph, src,
                predecessor_map(make_iterator_property_map(predecessors.begin(), get(boost::vertex_index, MyGraph)))
                .distance_map(boost::make_iterator_property_map(distances.begin(), get(boost::vertex_index, MyGraph))));
    }

    using Path = std::deque<Vertex>;
    Path getShortPath(Vertex destination) {
        Path path;

        while (destination != MyGraph.null_vertex()) {
            path.push_front(destination);
            if (destination == src)
                return path;

            if (predecessors.at(destination) == destination)
                break;
            destination = predecessors.at(destination);
        }
        throw std::runtime_error("Unreachable");
    }

    void PrintRawData() const {
        std::cout << "distances and parents:" << std::endl;
        for (auto v : make_iterator_range(vertices(MyGraph))) {
            std::cout << "distance(" << v << ") = " << distances.at(v) << ", ";
            std::cout << "parent(" << v << ") = " << predecessors.at(v) << std::endl;
        }
    }

    graph_t const& getGraph() const { return MyGraph; }
    graph_t&       getGraph()       { return MyGraph; }
};

void PrintPath(MyAlgorithm::Path const& path, graph_t const& g) {
    std::cout << "Path: ";
    auto idmap = get(boost::vertex_name, g);
    auto wmap = get(boost::edge_weight, g);

    auto previous = g.null_vertex();
    for (auto v : path) {
        if (previous != g.null_vertex()) {
            for (auto e : make_iterator_range(out_edges(previous, g))) {
                if (target(e, g) == v) {
                    std::cout << " -> (w:" << " << " << wmap[e] << ") ";
                }
            }
        }
        std::cout << "#" << v << " (id:" << idmap[v] << ") ";
        previous = v;
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}

int main() {
    MyGraphBuilder builder;
    builder.generate();
    //builder.printGraph();

    MyAlgorithm algo(builder.getGraph(), 1); // 1 is first vertex, not idmap

    algo.PrintRawData();

    auto p0 = algo.getShortPath(0);
    auto p1 = algo.getShortPath(1);
    auto p2 = algo.getShortPath(2);
    auto p3 = algo.getShortPath(3);

    for (auto path : {p0, p1, p2, p3}) {
        PrintPath(path, algo.getGraph());
    }

    // vertex 4 is unreachable:
    try {
        auto p4 = algo.getShortPath(4);
    } catch(std::exception const& e) {
        std::cout << "Error getting path for vertex 4: " << e.what() << "\n";
    }
}
```

Prints

```
distances and parents:
distance(0) = 15.3054, parent(0) = 2
distance(1) = 0, parent(1) = 1
distance(2) = 8.8954, parent(2) = 3
distance(3) = 1.52275, parent(3) = 1
distance(4) = 1.79769e+308, parent(4) = 4
Path: #1 (id:100)  -> (w: << 1.52275) #3 (id:300)  -> (w: << 7.37265) #2 (id:200)  -> (w: << 8.79559)  -> (w: << 6.41004) #0 (id:0) 
Path: #1 (id:100) 
Path: #1 (id:100)  -> (w: << 1.52275) #3 (id:300)  -> (w: << 7.37265) #2 (id:200) 
Path: #1 (id:100)  -> (w: << 1.52275) #3 (id:300) 
Error getting path for vertex 4: Unreachable
```

Comment: it compiles, but there is no result in print function, `//function to Print Out Results
void MyAlgorithm::PrintOut(){
  cout << "distances and parents:" << endl;
  graph_traits < graph_t >::vertex_iterator vi, vend;
  for (boost::tie(vi, vend) = vertices(MyAlgorithm::MyGraph); vi != vend; ++vi) {
      vector<Vertex> p(num_vertices(MyAlgorithm::MyGraph));
      vector<double> d(num_edges(MyAlgorithm::MyGraph));
      cout << "distance(" << *vi << ") = " << d[*vi] << ", ";
      cout << "parent(" << *vi << ") = " << p[*vi] << endl;
    } // End of Print Loop
}// end of Print Function`

Comment: I included the whole cpp code so you can see that there is a problem, but it doesn't appear on compiling, but after, as word After isn't printed out on console

Comment: Editing the question so that the answer is invalidated is not nice. It indicates that you should have asked a different question.

Comment: I apologize for that so much, I thought it will be annoying to post different questions from me on same topic on this website, so I modified the code, anyway you advice me to write the updated code on a comment or new question ? because I'm new to this website, I didn't mean to invalidate your answer, I repeat my apology.

Comment: Next time! Better yet, think about how you need to ask your question, so you don't post the bad version first :) I've updated the answer, see the **UPDATE** section and [Live Sample](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f298b135d49a850f)

Comment: I'm really sorry, I ask a question , then I try something to find another problem, so I ask again, and I'm working on this issue to generate short path vector of nodes through Dijkstra Algorithm , from a Graph built from Data Structure built from OSM File, I'm new to it , and I'm facing a lot of problems because I'm not expert, I appreciate your patience and valuable answers

Comment: thank you so much for your help, with that help I could do a small but nice project with shortest path between places in the city. [Map Project link](https://github.com/bhomaidan1990/Map-Le-Creusot-Project)